# Can maven-release-plugin create a tags in two remote repositories?

Tags: git, maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I have two maven repositories: **repo1** and **repo2**. They are not connected (I mean no  parent\child\dependency relations)

I want to use **maven-release-plugin** to create tags in the repositories.

Is the follwoing situation possible:

I execute `release:prepare` and `release:perform` in **repo1**. New tag and branch are created in **repo1** and in **repo2**.

If this is not possible, can this be possible if they are any relations in the two repositories?

I use git repositories.

Comment: So you mean having two projects which live in two different repositories ? So you make a release of the project 1 which lives in repo 1 so why do you need to make a tag in repo 2 of project 2 ?

Comment: The repo2 is the copy of branch of repo1. Some users do not have permissions to see repo1, just repo2. I want to automatically create a release of repo2, when I release repo1 to not do it manually. And I am not sure that the described action is the best solution here, I'm ready to listen to suggestions how to do it in other way :)

Answer (score 0):

The `maven-release-plugin` works only with the SCM-URL configured within a `pom.xml`.

It is not possible to create tags or branches in two different git repositories.

Maybe server-side [`git hooks`](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) could be a solution for you.

> [...]
>
> **post-receive**
>
> The post-receive hook runs after the entire process is completed and can be used to update other services or notify users.
>
> Examples include e-mailing a list, notifying a continuous integration server, or updating a ticket-tracking system – you can even parse the commit messages to see if any tickets need to be opened, modified, or closed.
>
> [...]

Install an `post-receive` hook on one git server and create a new tag or branch on the other git server based on your conditions.

Comment: Thanks, I will try.